# Optimizing QListView update

Tags: optimization, pyqt, pyqt4, qlistview, qstandarditem

I'm writing a logging application which is using a QListView with custom QStandardItems to display the log data. I have implemented filters in the app that will color the matching rows differently and when changing a filter I have to manipulate every item in the list, which after a while gets very slow. I'm not sure what's causing this yet, but I wonder if it could be that it repaints after every item change. If that is the case, could I somehow tell QT to not repaint until I'm done manipulating all the items?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How many items does it take for it to get slow? You might also want to show some code (since you are asking for optimisation help)

Comment: Maybe >10.000. But I think I solved it now. I used a worker thread who do this update and made the GUI much more responsive.

Comment: Ok. Hopefully you aren't actually making Qt GUI calls from your worker thread. That would lead to random segfaults.

Comment: I was thinking about that, does it apply to QThreads as well? What I currently do is that I have a run() waiting for a mutex. Whenever a filter is changed, the mutex is unlocked and the QThread will go through the whole list and update every row. It seems to be working fine even if I do very fast changes to the filters, so it doesn't seem to be any racing conditions.

Comment: Sorry, I realized now that I already made it thread safe. In one part of my application I send the incoming data to the GUI using a signal, and as I understand it all signals are handled by the GUI thread.

Comment: Reading from the list in a `QThread` is unsafe, mutex or not. If you emit signals, and these signals are connected (to slots) in the main thread then those slots can make GUI calls safely. If you need data from the GUI in your thread you need to either pass it at thread instantiation or emit a signal to the main thread, have the main thread put the data in a thread safe object (like a queue) and then read it out from that in the thread. If you are unsure, it might be best to ask a new question and post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For helping others, I could add that I fixed this by implementing my own view that handles the paint event itself and only paints the rows currently visible on screen. This makes it extremely fast and no internal QT view seem to be able to do something similar.